Combinatorial rule for Schubert times Coxeter-Schubert
For $w \in S_n$, let $\mathfrak{S}_w$ be the Schubert polynomial. For geometric reasons, we know that $\mathfrak{S}_u \mathfrak{S}_v = \sum c_{uv}^w \mathfrak{S}_w$ for some nonnegative integers $c_{uv}^w$, but no combinatorial rule for the $c_{uv}^w$ is known. What about the special case $\mathfrak{S}_u \mathfrak{S}_c$, where $c$ is a Coxeter element?
Here a Coxeter element is a permutation of the form $s_{i_1} s_{i_2} \cdots s_{i_{n-1}}$ for $(i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_{n-1})$ a permutation of $\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$.

Consider the standard Coxeter element $c=(1,2,\ldots,n)=23\cdots n 1$. Then the only descent of $c$ occurs at the last position, so it would seem that $c$ has "separated descents" with any $u$, hence the rule from https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.13855 would apply to give a formula for $\mathfrak{S}_u\mathfrak{S}_c$. (But maybe I misunderstood the definitions...)

Yup, and there is a more general version of this: $c = 234 \cdots k n 1 (k+1) (k+2) \cdots (n-1)$ is a Grassmannian permutation, so the corresponding Schubert is a Schur: $\mathfrak{S}c = s{(n-k) 11 \cdots 1}(x_1, \ldots, x_k) = e_k (x_1, \ldots, x_k) h_{k-1}(x_1, \ldots, x_k)$. Frank Sotille has a rule for multiplying a Schubert by $e_j(x_1,\ldots, x_k)$ or $h_j(x_1,\ldots, x_k)$ https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9505001 , so using his rule twice gives a rule in this case.

That's the complete list of cases that I know how to do.

(Typo above, should be $e_k(x_1, \ldots, x_k)  h_{n-k-1}(x_1, \ldots, x_k)$
